# For loop only keep last value from mongodb for on_press function

Tags: python, mongodb, kivy, pymongo

My for loop creates buttons depending on collection entries. but when making an on_press function, it only retrieves data from the last entry in mongodb.

update_interval works itself, i call it to update every 5 seconds to apply changes in the db (manually changing status of the place) but place_button.id will only provide id of the last db entry.

If I instead skip the for loop and create each individual button it'll work flawlessly, but will be too many rows and inefficient and of course, even if not so "important", new places wouldn't be added automatically if a new place is added.

```
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_interval, 5)

        def update_interval(self, instance):
            self.clear_widgets()
            client = pymongo.MongoClient("")
            db = client.workshop
            places = db.places.find()
            for place in places:
                place_name = place['place']
                myid = place['status']
                if myid == 1:
                    bcolor = 1,0,0,1
                else:
                    bcolor =  0,1,0,1
                self.place_button = Button(id=myid,text=place_name, background_color=bcolor)
                self.place_button.bind(on_press=self.set_place)
                self.add_widget(self.place_button)

       def set_place(self, instance):
            if self.place_button.id == 1:
                self.clear_widgets()
                self.add_widget(Label(text=f"Status changed of place {self.place_button.text}")) 
#This will result in "Status changed of place 9" no matter what button i press.
```

I expect the amount of buttons to expand depending on db entries, on press function should provide each buttons unique id/status/text etc. Currently it only provides the id/text/status of last db entry.

What approach should I take to this for optimizing the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always referring to the last item because in your app, you have `self.place_button.id` which is referencing the last `Button` object added in the `for` loop.

## Solution

Replace `self.place_button.id` with `instance.id`

### Snippets

```
   def set_place(self, instance):
        if instance.id == 1:
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.add_widget(Label(text=f"Status changed of place {self.place_button.text}"))
```